# Postinstall script in packgage.json

Tags: npm, bower, yarnpkg, package.json

I migrated my project from bower to yarn and now I have this

```
"postinstall":
"node -e \"try {
require('fs').symlinkSync(require('path').resolve('node_modules/@bower_components'),
'bower_components', 'junction') } 
catch (e) { }\""
```

In my `package.json`, what does the `postinstall` do?

Comment: There is no PostScript here.

Comment: @KenS, PostInstall I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postinstall` script here runs after every time you install a node package.What it does is that it symbolically links the `node_modules/@bower_components` directory to the `bower_components` directory. Hence whenever node runtime needs to access a file inside `node_modules/@bower_components`, it will redirect to the `bower_components` directory and access the file from there instead.